# How do I reliably detect an angular 1.* or an angular 2 application at runtime?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm trying to find a better way of detecting angular applications than searching for a class`.ng-app` or window.angular.

To help clarify, I either want to check somehow that the angular library is loaded or that an angular application is running.

Comment: what does `detect angular app` even mean? Better than what? And why would there be anything simpler than checking for `window.angular` and version? Question and problem are both really vague

Comment: Great...but why can't you just check for window.angular as you already mentioned?

Comment: it might not be in that scope. @charlietfl

Comment: if it's not there would not be much way to look for it. You can't guess where someone may have put it

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution?

Comment: @Jacques sorry I lost interest in angular.

Answer (score 1):

Charlietfl is right, your question is ver vauge, but something like this would easily accomplish the task of determining the major angular version.

```
(angular.version.major > 1) : alert("you are using angular version 1.x") ? alert ("you are using angluar version 2.x");
```

If you are looking for angular on other's websites, window.angular is your best bet. Put the above code in any application using the angular framework and you'll get the appropriate result. I'm not sure of a more accurate test than that.

Comment: yeah that was my 1st guess but it might not exist at the window level, but still be running on the page.